# When building Service Fabric project on VSTS, there are two build tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

I have a VSTS build definition that builds my Service Fabric project, it does this without problem.

When I look at the tasks in the build definition there are two build definitions one for [project name].sln and another for ***.sfproj. I did not create the individual build tasks, they were created when I used the Service Fabric build template.

Can anyone tell me why the *.sfproj build task is necessary?

Comment: *.sfproj build task is pack the package for Azure Service Fabric Application. And you can also find in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-package-apps#configure, you should specify .sfproj for msbuild command (such as `msbuild HelloWorld.sfproj /t:Package`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the MSBuild arguments. The first Visual Studio build task compiles your entire solution.
[image: MSBuild arguments build the solution]

The second Visual Studio build task packages your application for deployment.
[image: MSBuild arguments packages application]